# How to create a dynamic title for each webpage that can be shared socially via URL?

Tags: php

I've a site and it has a **News** webpage called something like **www.website.com/news/detail/id/3**. Now when I try to share this on any social media sites it is taking the title of **www.website.com** for any of the news details I share, i.e only one title of the website is being shown for any links. I want to see News detail page URL to be shared in a way that when a user clicks it it should directly goto that details page that is dynamically created on addition of every news in MySQL. I'm struggling to solve this and want anyone who has a clear idea on how to set the particular News or article to be shared using a url link of that news detail page on any of the social network sites. Eg.. as said above sppose I've a News Title lets say "**Welcome to Daniweb, the website for every technology to technocrats**" and its url is www.website.com/news/detail/id/4 When I share or post the above link it should show the news title as "Welcome to Deniweb, etc... followed by some part of description or image of that article. I hope you might have a clear idea about this. something we see on linkedin.com

1. How to change the id **4** to **News_title** in the url link and I'm using the Model, Views, Controller, then the url of a specific page I view must be of this kind eg. www.website.com/articles/welcome_to_dani_web_a_site_for_blah_blah_blah.... etc.
2. Where should I change the code to set the various titles for each webpages, that can be shared using a url link with the particular content of that webpage linked to that shared url. I've a common .../includes/header.php & ../includes/footer.php embedded in all the pages in ..views/scripts/xxxxxx.phtml pages How?
3. How to share the news using the url link that is dynamically created when someone posts an article. You may see in **Linkedin.com** of the articles being shared from some website, its image, Title, content is seen with url of particular webpage, Hope you have a clear idea of this kind and got me what I'm saying How?

This is how the code I've crafted and lost in it, not sure where I'm going wrong. Please 
Help. Specific part of the code is shared as shown below for your reference, .../scripts/news/detail.phtml page is as follows:

```
<div class="newsviewwholepad">

        <div class="leftcol">

            <div class="textnews"><br/>
                <div class="floatleft">
                <h2><a><?echo $this->queryresult[0]['News_Title'];? ></a></h2>
                <pa>By: <?echo $this->queryresult[0]['News_Editor'];?>, 
                Published: <?echo $this->queryresult[0]['Published_Date'];?></pa>

             </div>

                <div class="floatright">

<a style="color:#666;" href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=300" onmouseover="return addthis_open(this, '','[URL]', '[News_Title]')" onmouseout="addthis_close()" onclick="return addthis_sendto ()">Share</a>

Here I've used the addthis so as to share it using a button and it does not work, also when I share a complete url of the webpage on social sites it still does not work, HELP?

                <p><? echo $this->queryresult[0]['News_Content'];?> </p>

            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the Open Graph tags http://ogp.me/ , that is the universal protocol for sharing web pages across sites like Facebook, LinkedIn and Twitter.

Just for your reference

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
...
</head>

...
</html>
```

This will share your article across social media as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Although using Open Graph tags is a good idea if you want to target specifically sites like facebook, you can use other technologies to improve your actual situation in deeper way. Also, consider that Open Graph is/was based on RDFa.

For instance, you can set mod_rewrite to have meaningful urls. You can use, [dublin core](http://dublincore.org/), [microformats](http://microformats.org/), [RDFa](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-rdfa-primer/) or [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) to provide meaningul metadata on your pages that can be used by sites like facebook and the like or other systems like google.